# Why input number won't "move" the color?

Tags: javascript, input, colors, background, numbers

This is an attempt to show the input field selected with vanilla JS, just could think of changing background colors.

As a beginner I don't know if I am doing it the best structure. But sounds easier to me, in my personal project will be even more fields.

Now I just need to make the function keep one color at a time and not to select all at once. I did many attempts with conditional statements and subfunctions but no success so far.

[pointer/selector image for index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmMYt.png)
[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rodrigosebastiao/2d1e65e7/8/)

```js
var sel = document.querySelectorAll("input.arr");
var rcvVal = document.getElementById("ini");
var ini = document.getElementById("ini");
var arrLength = document.getElementsByClassName("arr");

ini.addEventListener("click", selector, true);

function selector() {
  var current = rcvVal.value - 1; //-1 for position 0
  if (rcvVal.value - 1 == current) {
    sel[rcvVal.value - 1].style.background = "#0D0";
    }else{
      for (var i = 0; i <= arrLength.length; i++) {
        sel[i].style.background = "lightblue";//go back to page previous/default color
      }
 }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "position: " + rcvVal.value + "/"+arrLength.length;
  //check position/length
}

selector(); //First run
```

```css
input {
  width: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  /*default color*/
  border-style: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  opacity: 1;
    padding:3px 3px;  
}
```

```html
Move one green color among input fields <br>
<input style=background:#E70; type="number" value="3" id="ini" class="first" min="1" max="5"> Selector
<br>
<br>
<input type="number" value="10" class="arr">
<input type="number" value="20" class="arr">
<input type="number" value="30" class="arr">
<input type="number" value="40" class="arr">
<input type="number" value="50" class="arr">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another way, without checking condition

```js
var ini = document.getElementById("ini");
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("arr");

ini.addEventListener("click", selector, true);

function selector() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].style.background = "lightblue"; //go back to page previous/default color
  }
  arr[ini.value - 1].style.background = "#0D0";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "position: " + ini.value + "/" + arr.length;
  //check position/length
}

selector(); //First run
```

```css
input {
  width: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  /*default color*/
  border-style: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<br>
<input style=background:#E70; type="number" value="3" id="ini" class="first" min="1" max="5"> Selector
<br>
<br>
<input type="number" value="10" class="arr">
<input type="number" value="20" class="arr">
<input type="number" value="30" class="arr">
<input type="number" value="40" class="arr">
<input type="number" value="50" class="arr">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: This example was easy to understand and implement, took seconds to fix in my project. And for default color this line also worked good: style.background = " ";

Answer (score 1):

It's because you set `current = rcvVal.value - 1`, and then immediately check if `current` is equal to `rcvVal.value - 1`.  Of course, that's always true, so the loop that resets the colors in your `else` clause is never reached.

You should get rid of the if/else statement and instead just run the loop to clear out all the colors, and then set the green color.

Answer (score 1):

Your if-statement will always result in the same block being executed since you set `current` to be `rcvVal.value - 1` and then check if `current` now is `rcvVal.value - 1`.

You could simplify it like so:

```
  var current = rcvVal.value - 1; //-1 for position 0

  // Iterate all of input.arr
  sel.forEach((node, index) => {

    // Check if current corresponds to the index
    // of the input.arr elements array
    if (index == current) node.style.background = "#0D0";

    else node.style.background = "lightblue";
  })
```

```js
var sel = document.querySelectorAll("input.arr");
var rcvVal = document.getElementById("ini");
var ini = document.getElementById("ini");
var arrLength = document.getElementsByClassName("arr");

ini.addEventListener("click", selector, true);

function selector() {
  var current = rcvVal.value - 1; //-1 for position 0
  sel.forEach((node, index) => {
    if (index == current) node.style.background = "#0D0";
    else node.style.background = "lightblue";
  })
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "position: " + rcvVal.value + "/" + arrLength.length;
//check position/length
}

selector(); //First run
```

```css
input {
  width: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  /*default color*/
  border-style: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
Move one green color among input fields <br>
<input style=background:#E70; type="number" value="3" id="ini" class="first" min="1" max="5"> Selector
<br>
<br>
<input type="number" value="10" class="arr">
<input type="number" value="20" class="arr">
<input type="number" value="30" class="arr">
<input type="number" value="40" class="arr">
<input type="number" value="50" class="arr">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude `.arr` at index `rcvVal.value - 1` using `.splice()` from an array created using `.slice()`, set the elements of array `background` to `"lightblue"`

```js
var sel = document.querySelectorAll("input.arr");
var rcvVal = document.getElementById("ini");
var arrLength = document.getElementsByClassName("arr");

ini.addEventListener("click", selector, true);

function selector() {
  var current = rcvVal.value - 1; //-1 for position 0
    sel[rcvVal.value - 1].style.background = "#0D0";
    var not = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".arr"));
    not.splice(rcvVal.value - 1, 1);
    not.forEach(function(el) {
      el.style.background = "lightblue";
    })
 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "position: " + rcvVal.value + "/" + arrLength.length;
  //check position/length
}

selector(); //First run
```

```css
input {
  width: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  /*default color*/
  border-style: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
Move one green color among input fields <br>
<input style=background:#E70; type="number" value="3" id="ini" class="first" min="1" max="5"> Selector
<br>
<br>
<input type="number" value="10" class="arr">
<input type="number" value="20" class="arr">
<input type="number" value="30" class="arr">
<input type="number" value="40" class="arr">
<input type="number" value="50" class="arr">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `Array.from` is a bit more readable than `Array.prototype.slice.call`

Comment: @E.Sundin Yes, where supported or by polyfill `Array.from()` could be substituted for `Array.prototype.slice.call()`.